# Phonegap+iscrollview = Scroll Bad

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, scrollview

I need a help with creating a list with scrowview in jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap. I'm using iscrollview and trying to take steps to adapt my application. In the example that comes with the scrollview use a div with data-iscroll and a list (ol), only this page.
I'm trying to put in a date-iscroll div within the body and a list inside the div, after she got to have another list without scrolling. But the scroll waging this does not answer correctly gets "stuck" in one position.
Here's my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"
        charset="utf-8" />

    <!--- STYLE --->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="style/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery.mobile.iscrollview-pull.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/smart_mobile_theme.css" />

    <!--- JS --->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/iscroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/cordova-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed"
                    data-tap-toggle="false">
            </div>

            <div class="content">

                <div id="listFilter"
                    style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10%; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 5%"
                    data-iscroll class="iscroll-wrapper">
                    <div class="iscroll-scroller">
                        <div class="iscroll-content">

                            <ul id="listVeiculos" data-role="listview" data-theme="d"
                                data-filter-placeholder="Vehicle" data-filter="true"
                                data-divider-theme="d">
                                <li data-role="list-divider">
                                    <div class="ui-grid-c">

                                        <div class="ui-block-a">aaaa</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-b">bbbb</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-c">cccc</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-d">dddd</div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <!-- VISUAL TEST -->
                                <li>
                                    <div class="ui-grid-c">

                                        <div class="ui-block-a">Frota 001</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-b">ABC 0123</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-c">R124</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-d">SCANNIA</div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <div class="ui-grid-c">

                                        <div class="ui-block-a">Frota 002</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-b">DEF 4567</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-c">FH12</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-d">VOLVO</div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <div class="ui-grid-c">

                                        <div class="ui-block-a">Frota 003</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-b">GHI 8901</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-c">1113</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-d">MERCEDES-BENZ</div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <div class="ui-grid-c">

                                        <div class="ui-block-a">Frota 004</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-b">JKL 2345</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-c">CARGO</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-d">FORD</div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <!-- TESTE SCROLL -->
                                <li>
                                    <div class="ui-grid-d">

                                        <div class="ui-block-a">Frota 005</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-b">MNO 2222</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-c">CARGO</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-d">FORD</div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <div class="ui-grid-e">

                                        <div class="ui-block-a">Frota 006</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-b">MNO 3333</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-c">TEST</div>

                                        <div class="ui-block-d">TEST</div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="content_div" style="margin-top: 5%;" data-position="fixed"
                data-tap-toggle="false">

                <div id="listActions">
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"
                        style="margin-top: 5%; border: 0px" data-theme="d"
                        data-dividertheme="d">
                        <li data-role="list-divider">1-xxxxxx</li>
                        <li data-role="text">2-xxxxxx</li>
                        <li data-role="text">3-xxxxxx</li>
                        <li data-role="text">4-xxxxxx</li>
                        <li data-role="text">5-xxxxxx</li>
                        <li data-role="text">6-xxxxxx</li>
                        <li data-role="text">7-xxxxxx</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Even my list has to have a filter. By adding this filter, by focusing on the search box, the listAction (list after the list that has the scroll) is on the list with scroll and filter it because of the data-position = "fixed" date-tap-toggle = "false".

Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved .. removed the iscroll.js and worked without problems. And the problem with the keyboard put the following code in the Android Manifest activity: android:windowSoftInputMode = "adjustNothing"